# Syntax error in SQL for create a table C#

Tags: c#, sql

Hallo ladies and gentlemen

I am strugling with what I think should be a easy solution but can't find it

Basically I am creating a table through SQL and there is a problem with the SQL when I run it.
Here is my code:

`OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
(@"CREATE TABLE " + ClientID + "
(Transaction_ID       INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Transaction           CHAR(255),
Date                  DATE,
Transaction_Amount    INT,
Balance               INT,
Deposited             INT,
Withdrew              INT,
Loan                  INT,
Applied               INT,
Approved              INT,
Payment_Monthly       INT,
Monthly_Income        INT)", mydb);`

Now I tested my SQL statement to found out which part of my SQL gives the error and I have found when I remove the fields`Transaction` and `Date` it works. If I remove only one of them it still crashes. I even tried to change data types like `CHAR(255)` to `VARCHAR(255)` also `DATE` to `INT`.

To be honest I can't seem to find the problem.
Please help

Thank you for your time.

PS: `ClientID` is a combination of three numbers and three letters with a hashtag for example. 123#ABC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those two column names are reserved words in SQL. Enclosing them in square brackets will solve your problem:

```
[Transaction] CHAR(255), 
[Date] DATE,
```

Keep in mind that any time you access these fields in dynamic SQL or stored procedures, you will have to use the square brackets as well, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM ClientTable WHERE [Transaction] = 'A'
```

Comment: A better solution would be to be more specific on those column names.  By Transaction does the OP mean TransactionId or TransactionCode or something like that?  By Date is that the date is was processed, the date it should be processed, the date it was approved, the date it was first entered?  A more descriptive column name would be advisable.

Comment: I totally agree, but there are times when the developer has no control over the column names and they must be able to have a way to handle these scenarios. For example, we work with a 15 year old app that has column names similar to these and based on the fragility of the source application, we cannot afford to try to change the column names, so we are left with this kind of workaround. Obviously not ideal, but it is a real-life scenario.

Comment: A bigger problem that wasn't addressed is the table name: naming a table starting with a number will _never_ work. Also, Depending on what flavor of SQL OP is using, the keyword `Date` for the column name may not need to be escaped (it works without motification in MS SQL 2012).

Comment: @Michael: I let the table naming slide because the OP said it worked when the columns were removed, so I assumed that the format of the table name wasn't quite as posted. However, the square brackets will allow you to create and use a table name that starts with numbers.